# Css issue when displaying web page into mobile devices

Tags: html, css, web

I have a simple blog on blogger, and recently I changed my css in order to display my recent posts side by side, rather than under each other, when in mobile view.

I did this by changing:

`@media screen and (max-width:640px){ .post{width:100%;float:left;margin:auto;padding:1px;} .post-body{margin:0;}`

to

`@media screen and (max-width:640px){ .post{width:49.9%;float:left;margin:auto;padding:1px;} .post-body{margin:0;}`

therefore fitting 2 posts before folding.

But now, when the page loads, it seems to not load correctly. Now this does not happen everytime. It seems to be random.

[How it is meant to look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGyxG.jpg)

[But sometimes it loads like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUekJ.jpg)

Could someone help me out?

Answer (score 0):

While I am not clear exactly why you are seeing random results, I can see that the layout may have a problem on some devices.

Take for example an iPhone 6 in portrait orientation. It has a width of 374 pixels so the total width of one of your 'rows', remembering to include the two lots of padding, is:

2*(375*49.9/100) + 2 )px = 378.25px

That is - wider than the screen width, so almost certainly wider than the parent post's width.

You could define everything in terms of percentages (remembering that padding if specified as a % is in terms of the item's width), making sure the sum comes to <=!00% of the parent's width. Alternatively you could look into other methods like flex or grid and get the system to work out what gaps to leave.

It is just possible that you see random results because of the lag in the system getting images loaded, but I'm guessing here and have no way of reproducing the problem myself to test it.

Comment: Thank you. I believe it was lag in the system combined with what you mentioned about the total width of my elements going over 100%. Using flex fixed it.